# jest mock: method syntax not recognized: `myFunc = async () => {}`

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

When mocking methods from a class with jest, I noticed that it works without any issues if the method has following syntax:

```
async myFunc() { return ...}
```

however, when written as follows:

```
myFunc = async () => {}
```

if returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined`

I, however, much prefer the second syntax. Is there any way to make it work with Jest (it works in the rest of the code)

---

context:

```
abstract class QueryService {
  async myFunc<A = any>(
      arg1: string,
      arg2: A
    ): Promise<{ uuid: string }> {}
}
```

in `service.ts`

```
class SimpleQueryService extends QueryService {
 // nothing here
}
```

in `simple.ts`

and then

```
jest.mock("../query/simple");

export const qs = new QueryService("host", "token");

const mockInsert = qs.myFunc as jest.Mock;
```

where the error occurs

Comment: Where are you writing these?

Comment: i just edited my question for more clarity

Comment: Where do you put the code `myFunc = async () => {}`? The signature of the method doesn't give me the context I need.

Comment: added more context

Answer (score 1):

For mocking functions, I would suggest using `jest.fn()`. You can also use it to mock the implementation like so:

```
qs.myFunc = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    // Your mock implementation
})
```

You can also simply mock the return value like this:

```
qs.myFunc = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(/* Your mocked return value */);
```